# Symfony 3.3 how add constraints to collectionType for two nested

Tags: validation, doctrine-orm, constraints, symfony-3.3

I have a symfony 3.3 form with two levels of nesting type collection.
how to trace the validation of the fields from the second level to the first. how to trace the validation of the last level of nesting ie the `$ amount` field of `PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType`. `only @Assert\valid()` does not work. Here is my code

BillingSetting

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * BillingSetting.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="billing_setting")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BillingSettingRepository")
 */
class BillingSetting
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Pricing")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pricing_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $pricing;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PricingMissionType")
     *@Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $pricingMissionTypes;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pricingMissionTypes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

PricingMissionType

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Traits\MigratedAtTrait;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * PricingMissionType.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pricing_mission_type")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PricingMissionTypeRepository")
 */
class PricingMissionType
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pricing")
     */
    private $pricing;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MissionType")
     */
    private $missionType;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypes;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $displacementCost;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BillingSetting")
     */
    private $billingSetting;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Traits\MigratedAtTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType.
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeRepository")
 */
class PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $sqlServerTarifClientId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PricingMissionType")
     */
    private $pricingMissionType;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(0)
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EquipementType")
     */
    private $equipementType;
```

BillingSettingType

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class BillingSettingType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('pricing', PricingType::class)
        ->add('pricingMissionTypes', CollectionType::class,
            [
                'entry_type' => PricingMissionTypeType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\BillingSetting',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_billingsetting';
    }
}
```

PricingMissionTypeType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PricingMissionTypeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('displacementCost', IntegerType::class, [
            'label' => 'billing_settings.displacement_cost',
            'error_bubbling' => true,
             'scale' => 2,
             'required' => true,
            'attr' => [
                'min' => 0,
                'step' => 0.1,
            ],
        ])
            ->add('pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType', CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => PricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeType::class,
                    'error_bubbling' => true,
                    'entry_options' => [
                        'label' => false,
                    ],
                ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PricingMissionType',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_pricingmissiontype';
    }
}
```

PricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeType

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('amount', IntegerType::class,
            [
                'label' => '(€)',
                'required' => true,
                'scale' => 3,
                'attr' => [
                    'min' => 0,
                    'step' => 0.1,
                ],
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_pricingmissiontypeequipmenttype';
    }
}
```

In my controlller

```
    /**
 * @Route("/add", name="billing_settings_add")
 */
public function buildBillingSettingForm(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(BillingSettingType::class, $this->addFormFields());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() and $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        /** @var BillingSetting $billingSetting */
        $billinSetting = $form->getData();
        foreach ($billinSetting->getPricingMissionTypes() as $pricingMissionType) {
            /* @var PricingMissionType $pricingMissionType */
            $pricingMissionType->setBillingSetting($billinSetting);
            $pricingMissionType->setPricing($billinSetting->getPricing());
            $em->persist($pricingMissionType);
            foreach ($pricingMissionType->getPricingMissionTypeEquipmentType() as $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType) {
                /* @var PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypes */
                $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType->setPricingMissionType($pricingMissionType);
                $em->persist($pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType);
            }
            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();
            $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('billing_settings.success.add_billing_setting');
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('success', $message);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('billing_setting_list');
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        '@App/page/billingSettings/edit.html.twig',
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'missionTypeLabels' => $this->getLabels()['missionTypeLabels'],
            'pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels' => $this->getLabels()['pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels'],
        ]
    );
}

/**
 * @return BillingSetting
 */
public function addFormFields()
{
    $billingSetting = new BillingSetting();
    $missionTypes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MissionType::class)->findAll();
    $equipementTypes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(EquipementType::class)->findAll();
    foreach ($missionTypes as $missionType) {
        $pricingMissionType = new PricingMissionType();
        $pricingMissionType->setMissionType($missionType);
        foreach ($equipementTypes as $equipementType) {
            $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType = new PricingMissionTypeEquipmentType();
            $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType->setEquipementType($equipementType);
            $pricingMissionType->addPricingMissionTypeEquipmentType($pricingMissionTypeEquipmentType);
        }
        $pricingMissionType->setBillingSetting($billingSetting);
        $billingSetting->addPricingMissionType($pricingMissionType);
    }

    return $billingSetting;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
private function getLabels()
{
    $missionTypes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MissionType::class)->findAll();
    $EquipementTypes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(EquipementType::class)->findAll();
    $missionTypeLabels = [];
    $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels = [];
    foreach ($missionTypes as $missionType) {
        $missionTypeLabels[] = $missionType->getName();
    }
    foreach ($EquipementTypes as $EquipementType) {
        $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels[] = $EquipementType->getCode();
    }

    return [
        'pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels' => $pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels,
        'missionTypeLabels' => $missionTypeLabels,
        ];
}
```

Validation:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="billing_setting_edit")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, BillingSetting $billinSetting)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $oldName = $billinSetting->getPricing()->getName();
    $oldMinPrice = $billinSetting->getPricing()->getMinPrice();
    $oldUnnecessaryDisplacements = $billinSetting->getPricing()->getUnnecessaryDisplacements();
    $oldDiscountByEquipement = $billinSetting->getPricing()->getDiscountByEquipement();
    $oldMaxEquipmentDiscount = $billinSetting->getPricing()->getMaxEquipmentDiscount();

    $editForm = $this->createForm(BillingSettingType::class, $billinSetting);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $entityManager->flush();
        $message = $this->get('translator')->trans('billing_settings.update.update_billing_setting');
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('success', $message);
        // Force doctrine to refresh object
        $entityManager->refresh($billinSetting);
        // For updating Elasticsearch data
        ...

        return $this->redirectToRoute('billing_setting_list');
    }

    return $this->render(
        '@App/page/billingSettings/edit.html.twig',
        [
            'billingSetting' => $billinSetting,
            'form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'missionTypeLabels' => $this->getLabels()['missionTypeLabels'],
            'pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels' => $this->getLabels()['pricingMissionTypeEquipmentTypeLabels'],
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you apply validation?

Comment: lxg -  I have a validation on the amount field located at the last level on the entity PricingMissionTypeEquipementType, I want it to apply on this entity without necessarily reassembled the parent BillingSetting. that it really shows me the error on this field there amount.

Comment: Can you post the exact code where you execute the validator?

Comment: I updated my question above, the code of the construction of my form and its validation

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you’re using the validator inside the Form component. Huh, strange … it looks like it should do a deep validation. But apparently, it doesn’t. :(